# Array intersection issue (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, duration, intersect

I am trying to carry out the intersection of two arrays in Matlab but I cannot find the way.

The arrays that I want to intersect are:

[image]

and

[image]

I have tried:`[dur, itimes, inewtimes ] = intersect(array2,char(array1));`
but no luck.

However, if I try to intersect array1 with array3 (see array3 below), `[dur, itimes, inewtimes ] = intersect(array3,char(array1));`the intersection is performed without any error.

[image]

Why I cannot intersect array1 with array2?, how could I do it?. Thank you.

Comment: First: convert the images to actual coded text, makes it easier to actually try your code. Second: since you are using times, using datenum or datevec to convert dates/times to numbers makes comparison a lot easier.

Comment: hmmm, try Array2 = Array2{:};

Comment: @GameOfThrows: If I try Array2=Array2{:}; I get a 1x1 cell array as a result.

Comment: @A.Visser:  I have applied datenum function to array1 and then I have tried to intersect the arrays but it does not work either:-(.

Comment: Your problem is the format for Arrays are different, you want to unify them, you can make everything into CellArrays by cellstr(Array1) cellstr(Array2) and then intersect.

Comment: @GameOfThrows: It does not let me to apply cellstr function to array2. I tried cellstr(array2) and I get the following error: 'Input must be a string.'

Comment: Oh okay! I see, Array 2 is a Cell of Cells, where each cell has 1 string.

Comment: >> whos array2
  Name        Size            Bytes  Class    Attributes

  array2      2x1               480  cell

Comment: Is there any way to attach my arrays as files in this forum?. It would be easier

Comment: I have fixed my answer, you want to do a vertcat(Array2{:,:}) to change Cell of Cells to Cell of Strings. Tricky one, didn't look hard enough at the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for ease of reading, your formats for Arrays are different, and you want to make them the same. There are many options for you, like @Visser suggested, you could convert the date/time into a long int which allows faster computation, or you can keep them as strings, or even convert them into characters (like what you have done with char(Array2)).

This is my example:

```
A = {'00:00:00';'00:01:01'} %//Type is Cell String
Z = ['00:00:00';'00:01:01'] %//Type is Cell Char
Q = {{'00:00:00'};{'00:01:01'}} %//Type is a Cell of Cells

A = cellstr(A) %//Convert CellStr to CellStr is essentially doing nothing
Z = cellstr(Z) %//Convert CellChar to CellStr
Q = vertcat(Q{:,:}) %// Convert Cell of Cells to Cell of Strings

I = intersect (A,Z) 

>>'00:00:00'
  '00:01:01'

II = intersect (A,Q)
>>'00:00:00'
  '00:01:01'
```

This keeps your dates in the format of Strings in case you want to export them back into a txt/csv file.

Comment: Thanks GameOfThrows. vertcat(array2{:,:}) worked. I did not know that array2 was a cell array of cells where each cell has only 1 string. That was the problem.

Comment: @Sarah Yes, I didn't realize that either, the 'String' suggest that it is in a cell, what you had was ' 'String', 'String' ', which could happen sometimes when you are reading in csv or txt files.

Answer (score 0):

Your first array would look something like this:

```
array1 = linspace(0,1,86400); % creates 86400 seconds in 1 day
```

Your second array should be converted using `datenum`, then use `cell2mat` to make it a matrix. Lastly, use `ismember` to find the intersection:

```
InterSect = ismember(array2,array1);
```

Comment: If I try: datenum(array2); I get the following error: 'DATENUM failed. The input DATEVEC was not an array of strings'.

Comment: The quotationmarks in array2 in your screenshot mark it as being a string. Try cell2mat first, then datenum.

Comment: If I try cell2mat(array2) I now get the following error: 'CELL2MAT does not support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.'